# Add an ics feed to Google calendar mobile app?

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Is it possible to add an ics calendar feed (from an MS365 outlook calendar) to Google calendar IOS mobile app?

I have added the link to the web app but can't figure out how to do it on IOS?

Comment: I believe this is possible. Everything that you add on Google Calendar web will sync to the Google Calendar iOS app (just make sure the same Google account is signed in on app). However, according to this similar post on the comments at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89475 (Sync Office 365 calendar to Google calendar), sharing via ICS link does not work very well with Google Calendar as it updates the calendar only once every 12 hours or more.

Comment: You would have thought so, but nope it doesn’t pull in the ics feed!

Comment: I see, that looks like an issue. For better support, perhaps you can report this issue further using the Google Calendar iOS app at https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110973?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1 OR to the official support forum for Google Calendar at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/calendar

Comment: Thanks @irvin, I have submitted feedback through the app!

Comment: @IrvinJayG. I've logged this under via the app, any idea if/when this might be rolled out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved. MS 365 ICS calendar feeds now work on IOS app.